# TextBox text highlight/cursor invisible when using template

Tags: .net, wpf

I have been changing the interface of my app with Styles, using ControlTemplates and so far, for sliders, buttons and labels all has worked out nicely.

But I cannot get the text of a TextBox to show any signs of being editable. It can be edited, but there's  no visible cursor or selection highlighting.

Here's my template code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource Dark}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Medium}" Margin="2">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" x:Name="tbText" TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I make text selections/cursor visible in this case? Am I using the wrong ContentPresenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the content presenter mainly. It should be a scrollviewer which is a PART of the Content Host. Here's your code with working addition.

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="2">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                            Focusable="false"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**EDIT:** Here's another example according to your next question of the default overriden textbox style took from Blender. Here you can see how to set up each of the property to customize literally everything.

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                            Focusable="false"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.56" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with the "selectability" issue.

A new question has come up - how do I style the content here? As in, the text color and, ideally, the selection highlight color?

I'm assuming it's the usual foreground and background brushes, but it seems like the "content" itself is no a yet another level with this change.

Comment: Thank you again! While the exact example did not work out for me it did show me the <Setter Property=...>, so this is working just as desired:

'            <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{StaticResource Accent}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionOpacity" Value="0.5" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Light}"/>'

One last issue for the look I'd like to achieve is the way the highlighting area is  drawn 'over' text, assuming it would be semitransparent. Ideally the highlight would be in the background, as is the norm in most cases.